# R studio: use only specific variables but being able to work on and not lose other variable information

Tags: r, dataframe

Hi everyone I need a little bit of help with a problem I'm facing, which I'm sure is quite simple but I can't seem to be able to solve it by myself.
Basically this is my dataset:

```
Age Gender Group  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
20     1     1       2   1     4
21     2     1    2      2     1
35     2     2    2         1
22           2    1         2
```

I see that many suggest subset/select function to perform analysis with specific variables, but what I need is to work from v1 to v5 to understand how many row to delete cause of the missing data but without losing the age, gender and group information. So I basically need to tell r to delete all row that from v1 to v5 have more than 3 missing data (which I know how to do it) and give me back a data frame with all the information of the remaining data (that's what I'm missing). Something like this:

```
Age Gender Group  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
20     1     1       2   1     4
21     2     1    2      2     1
```

I don't know if I manage to explain my self enough, but thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `rowSums` on selected columns. (columns that start with "V" and a number).

```
cols <- grep('^V\\d+', names(df))
```

If you have `NA` values as missing data

```
df[rowSums(is.na(df[cols])) < 3, ]

#  Age Gender Group V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
#1  20      1     1 NA  2  1 NA  4
#2  21      2     1  2 NA  2 NA  1
```

If empty cells as missing data.

```
df[rowSums(df[cols] == '') < 3, ]
```

---

Another option with row-wise `apply`

```
df[apply(is.na(df[cols]), 1, sum) < 3, ]
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Age = c(20L, 21L, 35L, 22L), Gender = c(1L, 2L, 
2L, NA), Group = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), V1 = c(NA, 2L, 2L, 1L), V2 = c(2L, 
NA, NA, NA), V3 = c(1L, 2L, NA, NA), V4 = c(NA, NA, 1L, 2L), 
V5 = c(4L, 1L, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked! I've one last question if possible for any future work, how should I change this code line
```{r}
cols <- grep('^V\\d+', names(df))
```
in case of variable with different name? Like V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 C1 C2 C3
Thank you again, you taught me a very useful way to investigate my data!

Comment: @CarloMarrone It is about getting the regex right. For example, if you want to select all of `V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 C1 C2 C3` you can use `cols <- grep('^[VC]\\d+', names(df))`. To verify your regex, you can also do `grep('^[VC]\\d+', names(df), value = TRUE)` and confirm if correct columns are getting selected.

Comment: Voted! Thank you again, I have to bother you one last time, since I thought I got it all right but I didn't.
Basically I'm wondering how do I use this function? Right now I'm trying to fill my missing data like this:
```{r}tempData <- mice(mydata,m=5,maxit=50,meth='pmm',seed=500)
summary(tempData)
```

I tried using what you showed me like this
```{r}
tempData <- df[rowSums(mice(df[cols],m=5,maxit=50,meth='pmm',seed=500))]
summary(tempData)
```
but it gives me back again only Vs values.
Thank you for your patience

Comment: I guess you need something like : `tempData <- mice(df[rowSums(is.na(df[cols])) < 3, ],m=5,maxit=50,meth='pmm',seed=500)`