# Faster way to use same code on slightly different named variables

Tags: r

many times using r I find myself doing the same operation for different variables with similar name (e.g, V_1, V_2, V_2 etc). Until now I've always copied, pasted and then manually edited  the number. So I was wondering if is there a faster way to do so? Writing the code I'm interested in and then letting r change the code for all my variables. 
If possibile it would be very useful to me learn how to do so! 
Thank you all

Comment: Can you please share a small example of what you're currently doing? It will help others to help you. If the data is similar to your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60808229/5977215), you can include the same `df` data here in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually what you would do is create a function for this and put all the code that you want to apply to the variable in the function

```
function_to_apply <- function(v) {
    #do something with v
}
```

then you can call it for one variable like this

```
function_to_apply(V_1)
```

If you want to apply this to multiple variables you can put them in a list and apply the function.

```
lapply(list(V_1, V_2), function_to_apply)
```

---

For the exact example given in the comments, it seems we need to apply function to multiple columns in the same dataframe. We can find out which columns to apply the function and apply them using `lapply`.

```
function_to_apply <- function(V) { 
     factor(V, levels = c(0, 1), labels = c(" yes", "no"))
}

cols <- paste0('V_', 1:51)
df[cols] <- lapply(df[cols], function_to_apply)
```

---

**EDIT**

For `chisq.test` and `table`.

```
function_to_apply <- function(data, V) chisq.test(table(data[[V]], data$Age))

lapply(cols, function_to_apply, data = df)
```

Comment: It seems exactly what I need! I've tried this
```{r}
function <- function(V) {
    df$V_1 = factor(df$V_1, 
   levels = c(0, 1), 
   labels = c(" yes", "no"))
}
```
and called it
```{r}
lapply(list(df$V_1:df$V_51), function)
```
But it do nothing, if i tried to add this:
```{r}
table(df$V_1, df$Age)
chisq.test(table_V_1)
round(chi_V_1$statistic, digits = 2)
round(chi_V_1$p.value, digits = 2)
}
```
It gives me this:
"Error in if (any(x < 0) || anyNA(x)) stop("all entries of 'x' must be nonnegative and finite") : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed"
Thank you very much!

Comment: @CarloMarrone I have updated the answer. Please check the last part of the answer on how to apply a function to multiple columns of same dataframe.

Comment: It worked, thank you!
Only if I'm not bothering you too much, How could I add the creating table part ```{r}table_V_4 <- table(data$V_4, data$Age) ```and the making a chi square test part? ```{r}chisq.test(table_V_4)```
Thank you for helping me so much!

Comment: @CarloMarrone Updated the answer.